# PHP MySQL search using WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have my following PHP code which finds the servers which have and tags assigned to them. In my example its bending, economy. The script gets a server that has both but displays it twice. What is the best way to stop this?

Please note that the tags are stored in a seperate table and are obtained by searching via the server id.

PHP Code:

```
$query = "SELECT s.id, s.name, s.ip, s.port, ss.id, ss.votes, ss.added, (1.6 * ss.votes + .053) * GREATEST(1, DATEDIFF(NOW(), ss.added)) AS score, GREATEST(1, DATEDIFF(NOW(), ss.added)) AS days, st.server_id, st.server_tags
FROM $tbl_name AS s
LEFT JOIN server_score AS ss
ON s.id = ss.id
LEFT JOIN server_tags AS st
ON s.id = st.server_id
WHERE st.server_tags IN ($sstag)";
```

Results 
[image]

Full script http://pastebin.com/5WHApEsd

Comment: . . Your question and your query don't seem to have much in common.  In particular, your question talks about tags and the query has no mention of tags.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to help clear up the problem, http://i.imgur.com/5xNprrx.png

Comment: So there can be multiple matches for a server in `server_score`, right? Which one do you want to use the `votes` and `added` columns from?

Comment: Your title says `WHERE IN`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in the query.

Comment: There can be multiple matches in server_tags

Comment: There's no `server_tags` table in your query.

Comment: Hint 1: This is merely SQL code not PHP code - in difference how you announce it. you can easily turn it into a string verbatim and then test to modify it in a database client later on porting into PHP code again. That should also help you to come to better conclusions more easily because you actually have the time to look into the mysql manual.

Comment: @Phyore: And you've added a screenshot to make the question more puzzling, not to clear it up.

Comment: My Php code echos out the results via a while loop, which is why I'm guessing it is being displayed twice.

Comment: @hakre the screenshot is showing what that queriy echos out via a while loop

Comment: Added full code (including output) to the first post :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join with a subquery that combines all the rows with the same server ID:

```
SELECT ...
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT server_id, GROUP_CONCAT(server_tags) server_tags
           FROM server_tags
           WHERE server_tags IN ($sstag)
           GROUP BY server_id) AS st
ON s.id = st.server_id
```

Alternatively, you can use your original query, but put `GROUP_CONCAT(server_tags) in the main`SELECT`clause and`GROUP BY s.id` at the end.

If you want servers that match *all* the tags, not just any of them, you can change to:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT server_id, GROUP_CONCAT(server_tags) server_tags, COUNT(*) tag_count
           FROM server_tags
           WHERE server_tags IN ($sstag)
           GROUP BY server_id
           HAVING tag_count = $sstag_count) AS st
```

You need to set `$sstag_count` to the number of tags in `$sstag`.

Comment: Hmm http://pastebin.com/uSLgLRiK Doing that now displays nothing =o

Comment: Fixed, I had the wrong colum in the ON clause. Didn't it get an error if you just copied what I wrote?

Comment: I changed $sstags to $sstag  Now getting `Column 'st.server_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Did you remove the original `LEFT JOIN server_tags AS st`? The above replaces that.

Comment: Just added a missing GROUP BY to the subquery.

Comment: Seems http://pastebin.com/v3edz9A7 returns all but the Last Element server which has both tags, seems to be searching for servers with either but not both. http://i.imgur.com/iRPARgw.png

Comment: That's what `server_tags IN ($sstag)` is defined to do: it matches rows that have any of the tags. I've added a variant that requires a match of all the tags.

Comment: It now displays :3 But it shows all servers so if I put in bending it'll display ones without it http://i.imgur.com/xYQdPgG.png
http://pastebin.com/w3Wq1Mhz

Comment: What do you mean "displays :3"? Where does that colon and number come from? It shows all servers because you're using a LEFT JOIN rather than just JOIN -- that means that rows in the main table will be shown even if there are no rows in the joining table. I did that because your original code used a LEFT JOIN, and I assumed you did it because you wanted the non-matching rows (why else would you go out of your way to add the "LEFT" keyword?).

Comment: Oh sorry I mistyped in the that im not sure where those quotations came from x.x Buuuut Removing the LEFT sorts it all :3 Everything displays as good now ^^ Thank you for helping me out and sorry for all the fuss D:

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are asking since the question and query seem dramatically different...  But try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (s.id), xxx, xxx, xxx, etc
```

Comment: +1 Whatever the cause of the issue is, this should help hiding it well.

Comment: Doing that still displays the same server twice, check the edit in the first post~

Comment: Can you show the code for your output?

Comment: Added to the first post :3